# Looking for an efficient array-like structure that supports "replace-one-member" and "append"

Tags: haskell, data-structures

As an exercise I wrote [an implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10230/python-implementation-of-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-problem) of the [longest increasing subsequence algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence), initially in Python but I would like to translate this to Haskell.  In a nutshell, the algorithm involves a fold over a list of integers, where the result of each iteration is an array of integers that is the result of either *changing one element of* or *appending one element to* the previous result.

Of course in Python you can just change one element of the array.  In Haskell, you could rebuild the array while replacing one element at each iteration - but that seems wasteful (copying most of the array at each iteration).

In summary what I'm looking for is an efficient Haskell data structure that is an ordered collection of 'n' objects and supports the operations: `lookup i`, `replace i foo`, and `append foo` (where `i` is in [0..n-1]).  Suggestions?

Comment: You could just use a mutable array.  I've had good experiences with [MVector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#t:MVector).

Comment: MVector has O(n) append/cons/snoc.

Comment: Why do you need `append`? The ultimate size is known from the start.

Comment: @n.m. The *maximum* size is known at the start, but for most input it ends up being significantly smaller than this.  Good point though, `append` is not strictly needed.

Comment: @n.m. An extreme case - for the input `[1000,999,..1]` - the result array never grows beyond size 1.

Comment: You are right of course. By the way such a data structure is not exactly trivial in imperative languages either. You can get close by doubling the capacity at each reallocation (this is O(log n) for `append`).

Comment: Thanks to all who replied - here is the application of the data structure, if you're interested - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10349/longest-non-decreasing-subsequence-in-haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the standard `Seq` type from [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html). It's not quite O(1), but it's pretty good:

- [`index`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#v%3aindex) (your `lookup`) and [`adjust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#v%3aadjust) (your `replace`) are O(log(min(*index*, *length* - *index*)))
- [`(><)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#v%3a-62--60-) (your `append`) is O(log(min(*length1*, *length2*)))

It's based on a tree structure (specifically, a 2-3 finger tree), so it should have good sharing properties (meaning that it won't copy the entire sequence for incremental modifications, and will perform them faster too). Note that `Seq`s are strict, unlike lists.

Comment: `Seq` is basically the best way to do this unless you're willing to work in `IO` or `ST`.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to just use mutable arrays in this case, preferably in the ST monad.

The main advantages would be making the translation more straightforward and making things simple and efficient.

The disadvantage, of course, is losing on purity and composability. However I think this should not be such a big deal since I don't think there are many cases where you would like to keep intermediate algorithm states around.

Comment: This page will tell you which type of array you should be using and in what cases:  http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays  Also, many thanks, @missingno